# MPXJ: How can I specify the start and end time of a task with resources assigned?

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

I was told to use the MPXJ to generate a project file with task that spans no more than several hours, or even minutes only. Everything seems to work when the duration of a task is specified in days, or if the task doesn't have resources assigned. But if the task has resources assigned and has to start or finish at a specified time (for example, at 14:35), despite I'm specifying the time in the code, when I load the generated file in MS Project, time is ignored. We can show the effect using [this](https://sourceforge.net/u/scap-ah/mpxj/ci/9d82de9953d56deb2304b586c7762f4966a36365/tree/src/net/sf/mpxj/sample/MpxjCreate.java) file included with MPXJ source code. Let's change the start date of the `task3` to include time:

```
//
// Create the second sub task
//
Task task3 = task1.addTask();
task3.setName("Second Sub Task");
task3.setStart(df.parse("11/01/2003 14:00"));
task3.setDuration(Duration.getInstance(10, TimeUnit.DAYS));
```

But when I load the generated file using MS Project, this is what happens:

[image: Wrong time]

How can I specify the start and end time of a task so MS Project respects it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the date format you are working with in the sample code is not set up to parse the time component of the string you are passing:

`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

You probably need something like this:

`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");`

Comment: I updated it before trying to specify the time. No, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll try to get an example working for you if I get some time today. On a related note, it looks like the version of MPXJ you are working with (based on the link to the sample file) is very out of date.

Comment: It's the code I found online. In reality I have the lastest version installed on my machine (I downloaded it a week ago). I have tried many things, even different file formats. Now I'm using `MSPDIWriter`, because it's the one that produces the best results (for what my boss wants me to do). Thank you very much for your help.